# setInterval executions too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is so many good post regarding this question after their own case, but i cannot find any good answer in my case.

**I have a multiple setInterval in different files which serves on their own functions:**

1. The application is a slide show directory, and i have one main `setInterval` which process the cycle of a custom slideshow in the main app.

   ```
   mainInterval = setInterval(changeSlide, 20000); execute after 20 seconds

   function changeSlide(){
      // .... do changes
   }
   ```
2. The other one serves as a idle timer when customer click on the information of a slide a modal will appear but when the there is no user interaction the modal will close. This function reside in another javascripts file.

   ```
   $('.item').click(function(e){
       // .. show modal

        idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // executes every 1 secs.
   });

   // This will reset idleTime when user interact with mousemove
   $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
       idleTime = 0;
   });

   // This will reset idleTime when user interact with keypress.
   // Since there is a side panel search engine will appear 
   // when a button search is clicked.
   $(this).keypress(function (e) {
       idleTime = 0;
   });


   function timerIncrement() {
       idleTime = idleTime + 1; // increment whenever the function is called

       // idleTime is more than 10 secs?
       // If true (10 secs is met) close the search panel if open
       //  and close the modal.
       if (idleTime > 10) {  

           // ... close the search panel if open
           // ... hides modal

           clearInterval(idleInterval);
       }
   }
   ```

---

> UPDATE

Since there is a modal will show when `.item` is click and in order to avoid multiple setInterval.

I handle the `clearInterval(IdleInterval)` when modal hides event triggered.

```
$('#item-modal').on('hide.uk.modal', function(e){
    clearInterval(idleInterval);
});
```

---

#### Now the biggest problem is the modal closes before actual 10 seconds is met, when i print the `console.log(idleTime);` bang! i saw the timer executes faster than normal.

Comment: Did you click multiple times? If you click twice, multiple timer dispatchers run at the same time, each incrementing the same global variable.

Comment: oh there is `clearInterval(idleInterval)` in the when modal hides to handle this. i will update the question more

Comment: I would rather use `setInterval(function(){  // do something },1000);`

Comment: also if you had nested `item` would create multiple intervals. Nobody can help without  demo that reproduces this...all we can do is guess

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `setInterval(my_defined_func, 10000);` and `setInterval(function(){ // do something },1000);`

Comment: There is nothing such difference but only thing is the binding scope will change if you call the function in some other context then second option is best and second option is useful when you want to send some parameter to the callback function

Comment: think that is a good idea ill work for it

Comment: What does faster mean? Is it closed after 9 instead 10 secondes after the last interaction. Or even less then 9 seconds?

Comment: it executes someting like 500ms instead of 1000ms so instead of 10 it count as 5

Comment: If it is really about half the time the the only plausible explanation is, that you  register the `setInterval` twice e.g. if you have nested items with the `item` class. Did you already try what `synthet1c` suggested in the answer and added the `clearInterval` right before the `setInterval`?

Comment: @t.niese yeah and it did works

Comment: But you need to keep in mind that the problem that your callback that create  the interval is still called twice. So even that `clearInterval` _solves_ your time problem, you still should check why the callback is called twice, because this might lead to other problems later.

Comment: @t.niese i don't understand what you  mean it is called twice? i have multiple `.item` in a single file though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not reset the interval every time the `.item` is clicked which may have caused an issue with multiple intervals running

```js
// explicitely save the state you will be modifying to the window
var idleInterval = null
var idleTime = 0

$('.item').click(function(e) {
  // clear the interval if it's set
  clearInterval(idleInterval)
  idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000);
});

var resetIdleTime = function(e) {
  idleTime = 0;
}
$(this)
  .mousemove(resetIdleTime)
  .keypress(resetIdleTime);

function timerIncrement() {
  idleTime = idleTime + 1;
  console.log(idleTime)
  if (idleTime > 2) {
    alert('show modal')
    clearInterval(idleInterval);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">this is the item</div>
```